# Find an element in javascript array using array.find()

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

How to search for an element in a javascript array using find?

```
 const array = [{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": "val3",
    "key4": "val4",
    "key5": "val5",
},
{
    "key1": "val6",
    "key2": "val7",
    "key3": "val8",
    "key4": "val9",
    "key5": "val10"
}]
```

I want to search for value `searchvalue`. I assume it will match `val1` and if so, I want to get `key5`:

`array.find((element) => element.key1 === searchvalue).key5)`

But if there is no matching `element.key1 === searchvalue`, then I want to search `key2` and find key6 of the result:

`array.find((element) => element.key2 === searchvalue).key5)`

As of now what I do is:

```
var arrayElement = array.find((element) => element.key1 === 
    searchvalue)
const value =  (arrayElement !== undefined ) ? arrayElement.key5: array.find((element) => element.key2 === 
    searchvalue).key6;
```

Comment: corrected the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chain the attempts to find an object and get the value from it.

```js
var array = [{ key1: "val1", key2: "val2", key3: "val3", key4: "val4", key5: "val5" }, { key1: "val6", key2: "val7", key3: "val8", key4: "val9", key5: "val10" }],
    searchvalue = "val7",
    result = 
        (array.find(o => o.key1 === searchvalue) || {}).key5 ||
        (array.find(o => o.key2 === searchvalue) || {}).key4;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: sorry, have edited the question, if the initial search is not successful, then search criteria and result key changes

Comment: as long as the value is truthy, you could chain the findings and take an object as default object.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is array of object. So you can make another iteration over the object keys using `.some()` to find the match

```js
const array = [
    {"key1": "val1","key2": "val2","key3": "val3","key4": "val4","key5": "val5",},
    {"key1": "val6","key2": "val7","key3": "val8","key4": "val9","key5": "val10",}]

const search = 'val6';
const res = (array.find(i => Object.keys(i).some(k => search === i[k])) || {}).key5
console.log(res)
```

Comment: sorry, have edited the question, if the initial search is not successful, then search criteria and result key changes

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over values of each element in array and match them with search value if found return that element or else use an empty object as default value, later access key5 on found value

```js
const array = [{"key1": "val1","key2": "val2","key3": "val3","key4": "val4","key5": "val5",},{"key1": "val6","key2": "val7","key3": "val8","key4": "val9","key5": "val10",}]

let find = (arr,searchValue) => (arr.find(v => {
  return Object.values(v).some(value => value === searchValue)
}) || {}).key5

console.log(find(array,'val3'))
console.log(find(array,'no matching value'))
```

Comment: have edited the question, if the initial search is not successful, then search criteria and result key changes